# How can I write a client side cryption same as node js server side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption

I'm using Vue and Typescript in my client side, I assume the client side code can return the same result as the server side function, but it does not work.(When passing the same params to the two functions, the results are different. )

```js
// server side
import crypto from 'crypto';

const cipherPwd = (pwd, key) => {
  const ciph = crypto.createCipher("aes192", key);
  return ciph.update(pwd, "utf8", "base64") + ciph.final("base64");
};

// client side (using crypto-js because crypto can't be used in client)
import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';

private cipherPwd(pwd: string, key: string): string {
  const keyArr = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(key);
  const ivArr = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('');
  const json = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(pwd, keyArr, { iv: ivArr });
  return json.ciphertext.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
}
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: The results of the two functions are different.

Comment: What is the difference?

Comment: For example, passing 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' as pwd to both functions, the client side returns 2oO60SRQtg+rrcXHlmJ2X/ruu+64DzFfOGJD/t93G6U= and the server side returns TohCrf00hB4s2tLmvg2ugxc=

Comment: The first one is AES 192 maybe the server version is different.

Comment: "CryptoJS supports AES-128, AES-192, and AES-256. It will pick the variant by the size of the key you pass in. " In my case, the string length of my key is 24, so the second function is also using AES 192.